# My LapTop Keeps crashing

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, display, freeze, crash

I have an acer aspire laptop that keeps crashing and freezing, I don't know whether it's the Screen or the Graphic card problem and what should i do to fix it.
Here is an image to help diagnose the problem
[image]

and a youtube link of the crashing  https://youtu.be/YYmySjVKZSk
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you set up remote access, you should be able to access it. I recommend VNC or TeamViewer, as these sign into your existing session; other software, like Microsoft Remote Desktop start a new session, where you may be less able to test problems on your session. Once connected, there are numerous diagnostic tests that you can run. By the way, your YouTube link gives an unavailable video.

Comment: thanks for ur answer, fixed the youtube link, after the crash happens I restart the laptop it works fine i can acces it but it happens again after some time so what types of test can I perform !

Comment: You need to set up remote access while it is working, and check that you can connect to the laptop. Have you really got an external graphics card in your laptop, or have you mis-tagged the question? One simple test is to change the screen resolution temporarily; this change will reset the graphics.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is almost likely a graphics card issue.  If you see the bottom of the screen the words "Well, if you won't talk to me" are correctly rendered - this implies that there is corruption happening in the graphics card memory.

You have not indicated the exact model of laptop, and there are lots of possible issues (mainly hardware I'm guessing), but its conceivable the issue relates, or can be mitigated by playing with the screen-casting setup - next time it happens, try holding down the Fn key and tapping the F5 key to see what happens if you switch video outputs.